# RediSearch fails to aggregate when 1kk+ keys

Tags: redis, redisearch, redis-om-spring

when i do the aggregation for 1 day the result is returned here is an example query
FT.AGGREGATE myIndex '@date:[1632776400000 1632862800000]' GROUPBY 1 @name REDUCE COUNT 0 AS count SORTBY 2 @count DESC MAX 10

but if you remove the filters,
FT.AGGREGATE myIndex '*' GROUPBY 1 @name REDUCE COUNT 0 AS count SORTBY 2 @count DESC MAX 10.  (OR  LIMIT 0 10)

then this will return

1. (integer) 65799
   (0.55s)

now only 1kk keys

why is this happening? how to get the result for the entire database?

Answer (score 3):

default timeout is 500 ms
fix it -> FT.CONFIG SET TIMEOUT 1000